# PhpStorm doesn't see translations when moved to app/Resources

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I had some translations in my bundles, for example in `src/Bundle/AppBundle/Resources/translations` but when I moved it to `app/Resources/AppBundle/translations` in my Twig templates it shows that translations are missing. I've tried invalidating cache and restarting the IDE but it didn't help.

How can I fix this?

My PhpStorm version: `2017.2.1`.

Comment: PhpStorm itself knows nothing about your Symfony-specific project structure. It must be Symfony plugin that provided that recognition/help in first place. So check the Symfony plugin settings; check existing tickets on GitHub for that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony Documentation:

"Each time you create a new translation resource (or install a bundle that includes a translation resource), be sure to clear your cache so that Symfony can discover the new translation resources"

Phpstorm may be processing by reading the cache files.

Try clearing the Symfony cache.

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

Optimize Composer.

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is fixed in PhpStorm Symfony Plugin via https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1010